# Facing an issue while trying to install "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries" thru Nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to add nuget package "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries" to console application.

When i tried to install facing the below error:

> Failed to add reference to 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest'. Please make
>   sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

Comment: Are you using the package manager UI or package manager console?

Comment: Got it resolved as the dlls are missing.